# If I pass an array into a JS function it doesn't seem to modify that array. Shouldn't it be passed by reference?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reference

This Javascript function inside my class doesn't seem to modify the array that it's passed to it by reference:

```
this.filterEqualCities(this.birthCitiesNames, this.birthCitiesPositions);

  filterEqualCities: function(citiesNames, citiesPos) {
    var tempNamesArray = [];
    var tempPosArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<citiesNames.length; i++) {
      var name = citiesNames[i];
      name = name.split(',')[0];
      if(tempNamesArray.indexOf(name) == -1) {
        tempNamesArray.push(name);
        tempPosArray.push(citiesPos[i]);
      }
    }
    citiesNames = [];
    citiesPos = [];
    for(var i=0; i<tempNamesArray.length; i++) {
      citiesNames.push(tempNamesArray[i]);
      citiesPos.push(tempPosArray[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Which array is not getting modified? citiesPos?

Comment: Well it seems you are reassigning array to empty; citiesNames = [];
    citiesPos = []; and that's why its losing reference

Comment: you can simply do citiesNames.length = 0 to retain reference and empty array parallely

Comment: `citiesNames` is the array as it's passed in, but towards the end of the function you have `citiesNames = []`, which means it is now a different array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It doesn't work even if I do that:                                       var citiesLenDiff = citiesNames.length - tempNamesArray.length;
    citiesNames.splice(-1, citiesLenDiff);
    for(var i=0; i<tempNamesArray.length; i++) {
      citiesNames[i] = (tempNamesArray[i]);

Comment: It is not that if I pass an object it should get modified inside the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: I think you are conflating pass-by-reference/value, reference type values and mutable values. These are all different things. JavaScript objects are mutable, reference-type values. That means that multiple "places" can have a reference to the same object and each "place" can mutate it. JavaScript is still a pass-by-value language. *Pass-by-x* really only describes the relationship between variables/parameters, which is independent of their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
citiesNames = [];
citiesPos = [];
```

the variables are no longer references to the original arrays that were passed in, now they're references to these two empty arrays.

If you want to clear out the original arrays, you can simply set their lengths:

```
citiesNames.length = 0;
citiesPos.length = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, how can I set your answer as the accepted one?

Comment: Since I'm a new member with less than 15 reputation points, my vote will be recorded but not publicly displayed

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit upon @Barmar's excellent answer - the issue is that arrays and other objects are not *really* "passed by reference" in Javascript, even though it seems that way a lot of the time, and it's often described that way. They're passed by value, like all other variables - but that "value" is itself a "reference" to an actual value stored in memory, not to another variable itself.

So if you were to modify `citiesNames`, say by `push`ing a new element onto it, that would be reflected outside the function - because you'd be modifying that shared value to which both `citiesNames` variables (local and global) are references to.

But when you do `citiesNames=[]`, you're taking the `citiesNames` local variable and reassigning it to a completely new value, and there's no way your other `citiesNames` variable can know about that.

This behaviour isn't unique to Javascript. Python certainly behaves the same way (and perhaps others too that I'm not as familiar with).

Comment: Thanks Robin! This surely clarifies it a lot for me